# What is the best way to write a form in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

What is the the best way to write a form to submit some data in ASP.NET MVC? Is it as [Scott Guthrie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Guthrie) demonstrates here? Are there better approaches? Perhaps with less using of strings?

[image]

Comment: It's mostly a matter of preference, there's a bit of performance gain using strings, but for most web apps it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like strings in my code, as it isn't possible to refactor. A nice way is to use Linq Expressions. If you get passed a model as ViewData you can use the following statement:

```
<%= ShowDropDownBox(viewData => viewData.Name); %>
...

public static string ShowDropDownList<T>(this HtmlHelper html, Expression<Action<T>> property)
{
    var body = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (body == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a method call.");
    if (body.Object != action.Parameters[0])
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Method call must target lambda argument.");
    string propertyName = body.Method.Name;
    string typeName = typeof(T).Name;

    // now you can call the original method
    html.Select(propertyName, ... );
}
```

I know the original solution is performing faster but I think this one is much cleaner.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And also we can get rid of Action="Update" magic string by using T4MVC